# Connect to databases on different servers using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, web-config

How do I connect to databases on different servers. I have a server which has its connectionString stored in  of the Web Config. How do I add connection Strings of Other databases in the  and read it using C# .
Severs are Sql Servers..
Any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

connection strings in configuration section are "keyed" and are referred to in the code using that key.  Just put two of them in there with different keys... 
Review [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178411%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in MSDN

Comment: I tried putting all the connectionStrings inside the connectionStrings section of the Web.Config file and reading it by creating a new instance of SqlConnection for each server. But that somehow doesnt work.

Comment: You can usually find answers for any exception you get. "Somehow" isn't specific enough. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste your connectionstrings from the web config? You can replace the server name with a dummy name. Also, the code you have written to access it. Are you saying you want to programmatically add the connection strings in the configuration file?

Here is how my connectionstrings section looks like:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="WCFServiceClientApp.Settings1.ConnectionString" connectionString="sfdffdfd" />
    <add name="WCFServiceClientApp.Settings1.ConnectionString2" connectionString="sdsyyyyyyyyydsdsdkokok" />
  <add name="WCFServiceClientApp.Settings1.ConnectionString3" connectionString="msdkokok" />
</connectionStrings>
```

[image: Snapshot of settings file]
[image]

Comment: So if I have connection String in the web config as follows
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Location1"
connectionString="server=ServerName;Database=DB1;User Id=Username; Password=Pwd"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
<add name="Location2"
connectionString="server=Server2;Database=DB2;User Id=Username; Password=Pwd"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
To read the connection Strings I used 
Sqlconnection connect 1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Location1"].ConnectionString);
And same for the second connection string Is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: Looks right to me. You don't have to explicitly open the web configuration file as the example in the article suggests. It should access it by default. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178411%28v=vs.100%29.aspx So what's the error you get when you try to access another string?

Comment: I didnt get any error. The Web.Config file has a connection string stored in the application settings i.e <applicationSettings>. I tried to comment that out and use connectionString with the method  written above. It didn't work. My website still showed data of the location whose connection string was stored in <applicationSetting>

Comment: It is strange that it is accessing a connection string that's been essentially deleted. Does not make much sense. Check if you have hardcoded that connection string in the code somewhere. I have been in that loop before. Also, when you regenerate the new configuration file and deploy it to the webserver, open it and check if the connection string shows up in the appsettings section.

Comment: There is a Settings.designer file in the application folder which has the connectionStrings stored under DefaultSettingValueAttribute tag . 
When I try to change the server name , Database, user name and password inside the <applicationSettings> tag it works.. However when I comment out the <applicationSettings>  and try to access using the above method , it doesn't work

Comment: What is the access modifier of the ConnectionStrings in the Settings file? Set it to public. When you add a new connectionstring in the settings file, does it get reflected in the web configuration file on compilation? Also, when adding new connection string into the web configuration file, follow the same naming convention. For example, if the connection string in the settings file is called A.B.cn1 in the web configuration file, the new one you add in the web configuration file should be something like A.B.cn2. Let me know what you find.

Comment: Access modifier ? I don't see any access modifier in the Settings file. I tried adding the connection string in the .settings file , But it didnt show up in the web config file. So I tried to write the connection string in the Web Config itself. Then I tried to access the connection string using the method mentioned in the comments written above. I still get the same connection. Is there any way to regenrate the .designer.cs file ?

Comment: The reason you don't see it in the web configuration file is because it is marked internal (I believe). Look above the settingsFileName.settings file. You should see Synchronize, View Code, Access Modifier. Also the scope of the connectionstring should be Application. Look in the answer section for more details I added.

Comment: I can see the Synchronize, View Code, and Access Modifier but I am not able to access it (highlighted grey).